# Getting n chars from string

Tags: ruby

I want to find method to iterating through string and getting each n chars from. Result should be similar like in [each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) method for array.

Do you now about some existing method or how to implement own method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String#each_char`:

```
"abcdef".each_char.each_cons(3) { |a| p a }
["a", "b", "c"]
["b", "c", "d"]
["c", "d", "e"]
["d", "e", "f"]
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want "consecutive strings" of length 3:

```
r = /
    (?=       # begin a positive lookahead
      ((.{3}) # match any three characters in capture group 1
    )         # close the positive lookahead
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

"abcdef".scan(r).flatten
  #=> ["abc", "bcd", "cde", "def"]
```

Written in the conventional way, this regex is:

```
r = /(?=(.{3}))/
```

If you wish an array of arrays of three letters, do this:

```
"abcdef".scan(/(?=(.{3}))/).flatten.map { |s| s.split('') }
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the other answer.

```
"abcdef".each_char.to_a.in_groups_of(3)
```

Comment: 1. `in_groups_of` is a Rails method.
2. Result is different.

Comment: Thanks I didn't think of that.